# UINavigationController Interactive Pop Gesture Not Working?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, gesture

So I have a navigation controller in my built for iOS 7 app.  The titleView is visible, as well as the back button and navigation bar its self.  For some reason, the interactive pop gesture (swipe from the left edge) isn't working.  Nothing happens.  When I log the gesture, it is not nil.  Is there anything special I have to do to enable this functionality?  What could cause it not to work?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Eh, looks like I just had to set the gesture delegate and implement the following:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Ive checked this but very creepy problem, when I have this fixed then if the user slides half way and then come back i see the next controller overlapped on the previous view controller. I see the Previous view controller and the next overlapped is transparent like transparent glass. So user happens to be locked this state. Any idea. This is something View did appear / will appear handling issue.

Answer (score 81):

I have found that when using custom back buttons, the interactive pop gesture stops working (my take is that Apple cannot foresee how your custom back button will behave, so they disable the gesture).

To fix this, as other mentioned before, you can set the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` property to `nil`.

In Swift, <del>this can easily be done across your entire application by adding an extension for `UINavigationController` like this</del>:

```
extension UINavigationController {

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
    }

}
```

**Updated answer**

Seems like setting the delegate to `nil` causes the app UI to freeze in some scenarios (eg. when the user swipes left or right on the top view controller of the navigation stack).

Because `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` delegate method cannot be handled in an extension, subclassing `UINavigationController` seems like the best solution:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    /// Custom back buttons disable the interactive pop animation
    /// To enable it back we set the recognizer to `self`
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but it turns out that under certain circumstances it freezes the app. I think it happens when the interactive pop gesture is triggered while a view controller is being pushed. A safer way would be to subclass `UINavigationController`. In the subclass set the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate` to self and prevent the interactive pop gesture from being recognized while a new view controller is pushed.

Comment: Indeed, I have found that issue too, seems to affect only the top view controller of the navigation controller stack. I have updated my answer with a different solution based in subclassing.

Comment: @Eneko Alonso perfect! Just as you said, if user swipes left or right and then taps a button - push view controller is glitched. Subclassing fixes the problem 100%

Comment: @EnekoAlonso Im having a similar issue when I set the navigation bar hidden. I loose the swipe back functionality. Is there anyway you can help out with this? I posted this question for clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954413/how-to-enable-swipe-gesture-when-navigation-bar-is-hidden?noredirect=1#comment84916434_48954413

Answer (score 18):

Look at this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21105349/1138755) and comments. All you have to do is set your navigation controller's interactive pop gesture recognizer's delegate to `nil`:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
```

Setting it to a casted self to `id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` also works because all methods in the protocol are optional, but I think setting the delegate to `nil` is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: i only had success with this when in viewDidAppear

Comment: This "works" but shortly after causes very strange issues to the point of freezing the app (tested with iOS 8, device)

Answer (score 15):

My answer is based on Eneko's answer but uses only an extension on UINavigationController and works in Swift 5:

```
extension UINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }

    public func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return viewControllers.count > 1
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working to me with IOS 13. Are you have any suggestion?

Comment: Worked with ios 13.1

Answer (score 12):

You can put this line in the **viewDidLoad** method.

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
```

Answer (score 12):

If you feel you have tried all solutions and stretching your head then you're at the right place.

```
Goto simulator > Window > Enable Show Device Bezels
```

[image]

Now tried to simulate swipe to back gesture.

Comment: This is so stupid, but it works! Why have Apple changed that?... Thx a bunch!

Comment: Thanks a lot SoftDesigner ✅.

Answer (score 6):

The more worked out answer was both Aaron and lojals

First Customise the Navigation controller and then put this code in the class

In ViewDidload put this line:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
```

And in class write this function

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer { return YES;}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe someone may find this helpful.

If you want to hide the navigation bar but use normal swipe gestures to go back and other navigation controller features, you should use: (**navigationBar**)

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```

If you want to disable navigation bar (hide navigation bar, disable swipe for back) but want to push viewcontroller you should use: (**isNavigationBarHidden**)

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Update 7-DEC-2018:

**Recommended way:**

In case that your first controller use hidden navigation bar, but next childs use navigation bar, when you come back to base view controller you will see a black bar in transition in place of navigation bar. This will be fixed very easy if you use in first viewcontroller(parent):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4, I have a UITableView inside my view controller, I solved this issue with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate=nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Generically add interactive pop gesture to the whole app.**

**XCODE**: 9.0, **Swift**: 4.0

Preferably create UINavigationController in AppDelegate.swift

1. Create a navigation controller

```
// I created a global variable, however not necessarily you will be doing this way
var nvc: UINavigationController!
```

2. implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

3. Instantiat `UINavigationController` in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

```
nvc=UINavigationController()

// For interactive pop gesture
nvc.navigationBar.isHidden=true
nvc?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate=self
```

4. Extra step, add controller to navigation controller in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

```
window=UIWindow()
window?.rootViewController=nvc
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

// BaseViewController is sample controller i created with xib
nvc.pushViewController(BaseViewController(), animated: true)
```

5. Implement gusture recognizer, add below code to AppDelegate.swift

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

**Note: See other post in this section for the difference between**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=true
```

And

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```