# Swipe back - interactivePopGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swipe-gesture

[image]

I have screens like this photo. HomeViewController will push to maintabbar, and a tabbar item will push to detailScreen. 
Why swipe back not working. I think it is default in IOS. Please help me

p/s: If i use SwipeBack in cocoapods, it working. But i don't want use it

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try setting the interactive pop gesture recognizer delegate to nil:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: Woah this works! Can someone explain why this is required to get the gesture working again, though?

Comment: @gokeji I wish I knew for sure.

Comment: It's not working on iPhone 7 Plus, please let me know, if you can help me here

Comment: Sometime setting the delegate to nil causes the app UI to freeze in some scenarios. More [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946302/uinavigationcontroller-interactive-pop-gesture-not-working#38532720)

Comment: Sometimes it causes a glitch in the Navigation Bar, making it disappear

Comment: I'm still getting upvotes seven years later. Does iOS really still require this?

Comment: Dec 2023, iOS 17.1.1. mix of swift UI and UIKit. Still requires nil-ing the delegate

Comment: Crazy, isn't it?

Comment: January 2024, it's still required to set the delegate to nil or self in an Objc x Swift project. I have no idea why the gesture doesn't work by default.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue which was fixed after this

```
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
```