# UINavigationController Interactive Pop Gesture only works first time

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, interactivepopgesture

I have been working on an app for some time and just realized the swiping back in the detail view only returns me to the master view the first time. It also isn't smooth, even when it works on the first time. Instead of smoothly going to the master view, it jumps all at once, even when I swipe slowly. It used to work correctly, but I haven't been testing for this specifically, so I don't know when it stopped working and what I changed to cause this.

A little about how my app is setup...

I have a split view controller that is connected to my `MasterTableViewController` and `DetailViewController`.

Both of those are have TableViews and are embedded in Navigation Controllers.

I have set it up so that the app originally loads to the MasterTableViewController instead of going immediately to the DetailViewController, but even when I take this out, the interactive pop gesture doesn't work.

I don't believe I've messed with any of the back button controls. I have looked through my code and storyboard and can't find anywhere that I have. This is part of what is most confusing because these questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946302/uinavigationcontroller-interactive-pop-gesture-not-working), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943916/swipe-back-interactivepopgesturerecognizer-not-working), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942571/how-to-enable-back-left-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-after-setting-le/42992396)) all seem to have problems stemming from changing the back button or can be fixed by entering the following line of code:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil
```

Adding that to my code seems to have no impact on how it behaves.

Here is a picture of how it is setup for reference:
[image]

I can usually figure out these things on my own, but this problem baffles me because it works the first time, but not any others. As far as I can tell, nothing changes between the first time and the others. I don't know if anybody else has had the same issue, but any help on why this might be happening would be greatly appreciated. I can provide code or answers to questions on how I am doing certain things if needed. I haven't put any in because there are so many different things controlling this piece that I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

When are you calling `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil`?
Doing this will definitely disable interactive pop. It sounds like you may be calling this after a certain `UIViewController` appears.

What other modifications to `UINavigationController` are you making? Are you using appearance delegate?
Are you subclassing? If so, are you calling `super` in all of your method overrides?

Also check your overrides of `viewWillAppear` in child ViewControllers. This method gets called during an interactive pop. If you are doing a lot of computation (or synchronous calls) on the main thread within this method, it could cause frame drop, hence the choppy animation.

Hope this helps

Comment: I was putting self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil in a class I made for the navigation controller

Comment: I haven't done anything else to the UINavigationController, not subclassing it at all

Comment: And, its not that the animation is choppy, it is just quick. As soon as I start the gesture, it finishes the animation instead of letting me sort-of pull the MasterTableView over from the side.

Comment: Remove `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = nil` and see if that fixes it

Comment: Nope, I had added that attempting to fix it and it had no effect. After removing, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

From [Alex Chase's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942274/6730558) : Also check your overrides of `viewWillAppear` in child `ViewControllers`. This method gets called during an interactive pop.

added it to `viewWillAppear` and it worked:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while testing my application on Simulator. I even tried creating a bare-bones project to check whether the pop interactive gesture was really working only once and it was. But when I tried to test it on a physical device, the pop interactive gesture was working smoothly and without fail under all circumstances. So, I can confidently say that this issue is only with a simulator and not with your code or the SDK.