# How to enable swipe gesture when navigation bar is hidden?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer

I've been trying to solve this issue for quite some time and cant figure it out. I have the current set up:

[image]

In each view controller I hide the navigation bar like so:

```
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
```

The issue is I loose the swipe gesture on the view controllers that the navigation bar is hidden. I need to have the animation enabled and cannot use:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Any help would be awesome as I'm sure many people has ran into this issue. Thanks!

Comment: user this code `self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self`

Comment: I tried using that but as I play around with the app switching screen it stops working. The app seems like it freezes but in reality one on the VCs are present but offscreen. I am then  able to slide it off. so weird

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the answer: Just subclass your NavigationController and do the following.

```
  import UIKit

class YourUINavigationController: UINavigationController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        }
    }

    extension YourUINavigationController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return viewControllers.count > 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think you mistyped the extension.
YourUINavigationController instead of VaultUINavigationController

Comment: @MostfaEssam That is correct and I just edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle swipe gesture by doing the following, and its will help you to avoid freezing the app.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)])
    {
        if (self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1)
        {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
        }
    }
}
```